# Redux UseSelect hook keeps re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, memoization, reselect

I've created three useSelector hooks and for the first one I change the value by dispatching an action with an OnClick function. When I do this my other useSelects get re-rendered even though the reference hasn't changed. Does anyone know why this is happening? I believe this is happening because I put console.logs inside the useSelectors and see them get fired off every time I click the button. minedDiamond ***should*** be the only value to change when I click the button.

Minecraft.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { connect, useSelector, useDispatch, shallowEqual } from "react-redux";
import { mineDiamond, fetchMinecraftItems } from "../redux/diamonds/actions";


const Minecraft = () => {
  const loading = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log("loading output");
    return state.diamond.loading;
  });
  let minedDiamond = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log("diamond output");
    return state.diamond.minedDiamond;
  });
 const names = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log("name rendered");
    let data = state.diamond.minecraftData;
    return data.map((i) => i.name);
  });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleClick = () => dispatch(mineDiamond((minedDiamond += 1)));

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchMinecraftItems());
  }, []);
  console.log({ loading });
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="wrapper__item">
        <img src="/image/pickaxe.png" alt="diamond" />
        <button onClick={handleClick} type="button" className="wrapper__button">
          Mine
          <span role="img" aria-label="cart">
            
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="wrapper__item">
        <img src="/image/diamond.png" alt="axe" />
        <span className="num">{minedDiamond}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="num">
        {loading ? (
          <p>loading...</p>
        ) : (
          <h1 className="num">{names}</h1>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Minecraft;
```

Action Creators

```
import * as Actions from "./actionTypes";
import axios from "axios";

//action creator
export const mineDiamond = (addDiamond) => ({
  type: Actions.MINE_DIAMOND,
  payload: addDiamond,
});

export function fetchMinecraftItems() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: Actions.MINECRAFT_DATA_FETCH });
    return fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((response) => response.json())

      .then((json) => {
        dispatch({ type: Actions.MINECRAFT_DATA_SUCCESS, payload: json });
      })
      .catch((err) =>
        dispatch({ type: Actions.MINECRAFT_DATA_FAIL, payload: err })
      );
  };
}
```

Reducer

```
import * as Actions from "./actionTypes";

//reducer holds initial state
const initialState = {
  minedDiamond: 0,
  minecraftData: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

//reducer
const diamondReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Actions.MINE_DIAMOND:
      return {
        ...state,
        minedDiamond: action.payload,
      };
    case Actions.MINECRAFT_DATA_FETCH:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case Actions.MINECRAFT_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        minecraftData: action.payload,
      };
    case Actions.MINECRAFT_DATA_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default diamondReducer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has nothing to do with the usage of console.log. 
Would you kindly include the code for your action creators and reducers?

Assuming state.diamond.mincraftdata is an array, the line

```
return data.map((i) => i.name);
```

creates a new array every time the selector is run. As per the [react-redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates):

> when an action is dispatched to the Redux store, useSelector() only forces a re-render if the selector result appears to be different than the last result. As of v7.1.0-alpha.5, the default comparison is a strict === reference comparison.

Comment: Yeah, I just made those changes! Minecraftdata is an array and  I think I need to use reselect to memoize it but I don't know exactly how to do that. I tried and I got an error, "state is undefined" in my createSelector().

Comment: You don't necessarily need an external library to help you with this, but if you're doing so anyways, consider [immutable-js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js). It will solve this particular issue for you with little effort, and will also help you out with more complex state trees.